# Is it possible to declare a method with block as default value?

Tags: ruby, lambda, block

I want to write a method which takes a block and if no block given it should use a default block. So I want to have something like this:

```
def say_hello(name, &block = ->(name) { puts "Hi, #{name}" })
  # do something
end
```

But when I'm trying to do so I'm getting the syntax error.

I know I can deal with my problem using [`block_given?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-block_given-3F). But I am interested in first approach.
Am I missing something or this is just not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some answers suggest using `block_given?`, but since there is no possibility that a block would be `nil` or `false` when it is given, you can simply use `||=`.

```
def say_hello(name, &block)
  block ||= ->(name){puts "Hi, #{name}"}
  # do something
end
```

Comment: Don't you also have to switch your method of accessing the block to avoid `yield`?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: If a block isn't provided on the call, then `yield` statements will not work. You have invoke it with `block.call(...)` or something equivalent.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin That is right. And, how is `yield` relevant? What are you trying to tell me?

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that this technique of assigning a value to `block` in the event the caller doesn't provide it is not a transparent alternative to providing a default value for `&block` (i.e. providing a "default block" to be used in case the caller doesn't provide one). The OP needs to know that if he used `yield` previously, he needs to change his code (i.e. the contents of `# do something`) to use this alternate approach.

Comment: I said as much in my answer and I'm suggesting you might want to update your answer to include that remark, particularly since it's the accepted one.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin No, I don't want to update my answer to make it less useful by including any unhelpful thing as in your answer. Since the OP is using the variable `block`, the OP should not, (and probably not) be using `yield` within the code; otherwise it is useless to accept the block with a variable. I see no mentioning of `yield` in the OP's question (which is the right thing), nor in my answer. It is you who somehow brought in `yield`, and is struggling over it.

Comment: So in your view, the `&block` parameter is only intended to be used when you want to reference `block` in method body? I understood it was also intended as a mechanism for simply documenting that the method was expecting a block.

Comment: See also https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/50679#19405 as an example of someone else raising this concern.

Comment: @user2422869 Wanted to call your attention to this thread in case you weren't aware of it.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Accepting a block with a variable and then switching to use `yield` is a bad practice. If you wanted to make clear of the block, then you should use the variable consistently.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot declare a default block in the method definition, however you can use a little trick to use a custom block if none is given.

```
def say_hello(name)
  block = block_given? ? Proc.new : ->(name) { puts "Hi, #{name}" }
  block.call(name)
end

# This example uses a custom block
say_hello('weppos') { |name| puts "Hello, #{name}!" }
# => Hello, weppos!

# This example fallbacks to the default
say_hello('weppos')
# => Hi, weppos!
```

Let me explain it a little bit. Let's start from a more readable version.

```
def say_hello(name, &block)
  block = block ? block : ->(name) { puts "Hi, #{name}" }
  block.call(name)
end
```

You define the method to accept a block, then you check if block is defined. If not, you assign a custom block. Finally, you execute the block.

Let's enhance it a little bit. You can use block_given? to check if a block is passed

```
def say_hello(name, &block)
  block = block_given? ? block : ->(name) { puts "Hi, #{name}" }
  block.call(name)
end
```

This also allows you to skip the declaration of the block (`&block`) in the method definition.

```
def say_hello(name)
  if block_given?
    yield name
  else
    # This is rendundant, but it's for clarity
    block = ->(name) { puts "Hi, #{name}" }
    block.call(name)
  end
end
```

But, at this point, you can also use the `Proc.new` to assign the block to a variable.

```
def say_hello(name)
  block = block_given? ? Proc.new : ->(name) { puts "Hi, #{name}" }
  block.call(name)
end
```

As a final word, I'm trying to understand when this approach would make sense. In most cases, you can probably wrap the code in a class or module and pass it as argument. It's probably better.

Comment: Didn't see your answer when I posted mine. In the event you use `&block` as a parameter, you don't have to define `block` as `Proc.new` if a block isn't passed, because Ruby takes care of that for you. Right?

Comment: I had to write that I know what `block_given?` do. :) Though awesome answer.

I'm currently playing with something that needs to declare a method on `method_missing`. eg `foobar { |x| puts x }` will add a method `foobar(x)` to current objects class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with regular lambdas.

```
def say_hello(name, block = ->(name) { puts "Hi, #{name}" })
  block.call(name)
end 

say_hello("Sergio")
say_hello("Ivan", ->(name) { puts "Where are you from, #{name}?"})
# >> Hi, Sergio
# >> Where are you from, Ivan?
```

Not sure if you can do this with blocks, though. A block is not an ordinary parameter.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't provide a default block value in a method definition. You can, however, achieve the equivalent behavior through the use of `block_given?` within the body of the method, as follows:

```
def say_hello(name, &block)
  block = ->(name) { puts "Hi, #{name}" } unless block_given?
  # do something
end
```

However, in this scenario you can't utilize `yield` to invoke any block that is passed in, since it won't be there in the default case. You'll have to invoke the `block` `Proc` object, as in `block.(name)`.