# why proc doesn't need to have a default value if it is an optional argument in ruby

Tags: ruby

In ruby, if an argument is optional, we should give this argument an default value in the definition, the definition is like below:

```rb
def my_function(var = 1)
end
```

However, if I have a function definition like below, it looks like this function should receive one argument and this argument is a proc, my question is why there is no error if this method is called without a parameter? If this proc argument is optional, why it has no default value?

```
def my_function(&prc)
end
p my_function
```

Comment: Related question: [Is it possible to declare a method with block as default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314478/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-method-with-block-as-default-value)

Comment: Probably for historical reasons. You can call any method with a block, Ruby won’t stop you. The method has to explicitly check for an unwanted block and raise an `ArgumentError` manually. (most methods don’t)

Comment: BTW, `&prc` doesn't make the block required. It merely says that _if_ a block is given, it should be assigned to the variable `prc` (as a proc). Without a block, `prc` remains `nil`. (the default value for all Ruby variables)

Comment: If you would use a block inside your function you would receive an exception. `def my_function; yield; end` would raise *"LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)"* when called without block.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, *every* method implicitly has a single optional block parameter. The `&` unary prefix ampersand sigil means "take the block that was passed as an argument, roll it up into a `Proc` object, and bind it to this parameter". Since *every* block parameter is *always* optional, and there can be only *one*, there is no need to explicitly mark it as optional. We already know it is.